# Openoffice.org Calc - Assigning value to variable

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I am trying to assign a value to a variable. 
 For example, I want "apple" to equal "$0.05". So if I type in this formula `(=apple*5)` into a cell, it should return "$0.25". 
I've been on YouTube and ran a search on this site, but I could not find anything that relates to what I am trying to accomplish. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

At least as of LibreOffice 24.2 (possibly earlier), this is achieved with *Sheet* > *Named Ranges and Expressions* > *Define*:

[image]

**Old Answer**:

You can do this under *Insert > Names > Define* - just use the constant 0.05 when assigning the name. You can always format the cell you use it in as currency.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! - It works as shown in the gif. The other piece to this is that I have a cell to the left that has the word "apple". So for example, if A1 has the "apple", and B1 has "5", I should be able to make the formula in another cell, let's say C1, that is "=A1*B1". But that is not working for me. I originally thought that the problem was that I had A1 formatted as a dropdown list, or list. But when I converted it back to All Values, it still wasn't working.

Comment: @MrGlass - the text "apple" in that case isn't interpreted as a defined name, but just as text. What exactly are you trying to do? There's probably a better way to accomplish it than using defined names. Taking a guess, you might want a lookup table to return values that correspond with certain text.

Comment: I run an eBay business and use Bubble Mailers a lot. One mailer may cost me $0.25, another $0.50. I want to calculate the cost of all the different mailers I use, so I want to associate a cost to each mailer. For example, if column A1 has "bubblemailer1" associated with $0.25, A2 has the number of mailers I've used, lets say 4 - I want the return to appear in A3 with $1.00.

Comment: So then have a lookup table - the mailer type in column 1 and the cost associated with it in column 2. Use `VLOOKUP` to lookup the mailer type, return its associated cost, and then multiply by the quantity.

Comment: MenuItem no longer exists in LibreOffice.

Comment: @GringoSuave updated for LibreOffice 24.2